# How to prevent reevaluating other rules on using update statement in Drools?

Tags: drools, insert-update

On using Update() statement in Drools, can we prevent the other rules to be reevaluated again ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `no-loop` or `lock-on-active` attribute. Check the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch05.html#d0e3761) for other options as well.